# use variable values outside each function in jquery

Tags: jquery, function, each

```
jQuery('ol.productList li.product input[name*="cart.pAsin."]').load().each(function(){   // each function 
    var asinId = jQuery(this).val();
    var pUrl    = jQuery(this).siblings("a").attr('href');
    var imgPath = jQuery(this).siblings("a").children('img').attr('src');
    var productTitle = jQuery(this).siblings("div.productDetails").children('h4.title').text();
    var descUrl = '/api/product/asin/' + asinId;
    var productDesc = '';
        jQuery.getJSON(descUrl, function(data) {
            var attr = data.attributes[1];
            productDesc = attr.productDescription;
            var allinfo = [];
            allinfo.push(asinId,productTitle,productDesc,pUrl,imgPath);
            alert(allinfo[0]);

        });
    });

alert('Asin id :'+ asinId + ' Product Url : '+ pUrl + ' Image Path : ' +imgPath + ' Product Titl : '+productTitle+ ' Product Discription : ' +productDesc );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access `asinId`, `pUrl`, etc as they are defined within the scope of anonymous function you passed to `each()` method.

To even make matters more confusing, the `productDesc` might not also be the value you are looking for, even if you try to access it within the said anon `function` as `getJSON` is operating under `AJAX` and is asynchronous, meaning the value of `productDesc` after `.getJSON` call can't be guaranteed to be assigned after `.getJSON` handler finished.

You could define asinId etc out of the `each()` method and then it'll be available outside the anon function scope:

```
var asinId = jQuery(this).val();
var pUrl    = jQuery(this).siblings("a").attr('href');
var imgPath = jQuery(this).siblings("a").children('img').attr('src');
var productTitle = jQuery(this).siblings("div.productDetails").children('h4.title').text();
var descUrl = '/api/product/asin/' + asinId;
var productDesc = '';

jQuery('ol.productList li.product input[name*="cart.pAsin."]').load().each(function(){   // each function 
   asinId = jQuery(this).val(); // notice this is without var keyword
   // rest of your code
});

alert('Asin id :'+ asinId + ' Product Url : '+ pUrl + ' Image Path : ' +imgPath + ' Product Titl : '+productTitle+ ' Product Discription : ' +productDesc );
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply define them outside the scope of your each()'s anonymous function like this:

```
var asinId = null;
var pUrl = null;
...
jQuery('ol.productList li.product input[name*="cart.pAsin."]').load().each(function(){   // each function 
    asinId = jQuery(this).val();
    pUrl    = jQuery(this).siblings("a").attr('href');
...
```

You can now access them from outside as they belong to the global scope now.